# Can a simple ether refund without storage checks be hackable(reentrancy attack, ...)?

Tags: solidity, reentrant-attacks, gas-refund, send

As the title says, I am wondering if the following ether refund(using .call) can be hackable.
I am not entirely sure no reentrancy attack can be performed in it, but I think so since I am not updating any storage for the contract nor checking any value that's outside the tx or that is not a constant in the storage.

Here's the stack:

```
uint256 requiredAmount = 1 ether; // just using 1 ether as sample

function myPayableFunc() external payable {
 require(msg.value > requiredAmount); 
 _processEther(msg.value);
}

function _processEther(uint256 etherValue) internal {
 if(etherValue > requiredAmount) {
  uint256 refundAmount = etherValue - requiredAmount;
  address(msg.sender).call{ value: refundAmount }("");
 }
}
```

I've just written it so I'm not sure it's completely "runnable" but guess gives the required details;

Basically what it does is:

1. Receive ether in a function
2. If received ether are more than needed, refund the remnant.

So my concern is:
Is this somehow hackable via the reentrancy hack pattern(or some other one)?
If possible, please describe why.

Thank you so much in advance for the answers

Comment: Try to run it through your mind, what would happen if you tried to reenter this?

Answer (score 0):

When implementing the [Check Effect Interaction](https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/checks_effects_interactions.html) pattern and adhering to its guidelines, you can protect yourself against reentrancy attacks, at least for simpler scenarios.

```
uint256 requiredAmount = 1 ether;

function myPayableFunc() external payable {
    // Check: Ensure that the sent value is greater than the required amount
    require(msg.value > requiredAmount); 

    // Effect: Perform any necessary storage updates (none in this code sample)

    // Interaction: Make an external call
    if (address(this).balance > requiredAmount) {
        uint256 refundAmount = address(this).balance - requiredAmount;
        address(msg.sender).call{ value: refundAmount }("");
    }
}
```

However, since the provided code sample does not include any storage updates, it is already inherently safe from reentrancy attacks.

Answer (score 0):

If a contract set up a reentrancy attack to call `myPayableFunc()` every time they received the refunded ether, they would be left with `1 ether` less than their initial deposit each time they looped through. In the end, they would be left with an amount less than the `requiredAmount` and the loop would eventually stop/fail. (and you would have all the attacker's ether)